# How much should I spend on scissors for grooming my dog?

Tags: dogs, grooming

We like to save money by grooming our dog's hair ourselves. It takes us a couple of hours every three months. Scissors has proven more successful than a shaver. But it's hard to know how much to spend on a pair of scissors. We've gone through a couple of pairs of cheap ones (around $20) and find that they go blunt after five or six usages. What sort of price range should I be looking at if I want scissors to last for at least 5 years or more?

Comment: Consider adding the breed of dog you're grooming as well as the type of scissors you're using now.  Some breeds require specific (sometimes more expensive) scissors or shears because of their unique grooming needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like a pair of scissors to last 5 years you should be prepared to commit to caring, sharpening, and cleaning them properly.  You'll be largely looking at stainless steel - there are newer, shinier alloys and such being marketed but stainless steel is solid and what most groomers/breeders (at least the ones I know) will recommend.  Also, the type of scissors you buy should be recommended for your dogs specific coat type (a bichon will require different equipment than a St. Bernard and so on). You can spend $20 and, with proper care, have a pair of scissors last a year or more - alternatively you could spend $250+ and without that same level of care have those scissors be basically garbage in 6 months. With that said you're likely looking at ~$100 per pair.

You might consider having your cheap scissors sharpened professionally - this would likely extend their life a bit, although professional sharpening and good care will never turn a $20 pair of scissors into a $200 pair.

Here are a few options for more professional grooming scissors.

[Chris Christensen Adalynn Series](http://www.chrissystems.com/shears/adalynn-series-shears.aspx) - ~$150
Chris Christensen scissors (and brushes) are well liked among breeders and groomers.  The Adalynn series is made with high quality 440C steel, and they offer a lifetime warranty as well as free sharpening for all their scissors and shears.  My breeder has had a set of Chris Christensen scissors and shears which have held up over 10 years - he has 10 Keeshonds (long fur, thick double coats) which he grooms himself using the same set of tools.

[Kenchii Scorpion 8" Straight Pro Dog Grooming Shear](http://amzn.to/2siyAaI) - ~$80
Kenchii is another well regarded manufacturer.  Scorpion is their base line, and will work well for most non-professional groomers.  A set of their scissors will last years, and they have a decent warranty although they don't offer the sharpening that Chris Christensen does.

Comment: Awesome thanks, yes i had come across the $100ish Japanese scissors and they seem like the way to go.